# Calculating Probability based on previous Probability values

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

So I am practising come exam questions on Normal distributions. I have this question which I can't quite get right.

$X,Y$ are normally distributed.

We have $\overline{X} = 100, V(X)=25, \overline{Y} = 120, V(Y)=20$ where $V(X)$ is the variance of $X$.

Calculate:

1. $p(X>92)$
2. $p(Y>X)$
3. $p(2X+Y < 300)$

Bits 2. and 3. are the ones that are new to me and I can't do. Any help on those is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can handle (i), then with a bit of additional knowledge you can handle the others.

**Important fact:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be **independent** normal, with means $\mu$ and $\nu$, and variances $\sigma^2$ and $\tau^2$. Let $a$ and $b$ be constants. Then the random variable $aX+bY$ has **normal** distribution, mean $a\mu+b\nu$, ans variance $a^2\sigma^2+b^2\tau^2$.

For the second problem, let $W=Y-X=+(-1)X+(1)Y$.  By the "important fact,"  $W$ is normal, mean $20$, variance $45$. We want $\Pr(W\gt 0)$. You know how to calculate this sort of thing.

The third problem will feel a little simpler, since there are no minus signs.

**Added:** For the second problem, we are asked for the probability that $Y\gt X$. It is convenient to rewrite this inequality as $Y-X\gt 0$, or, to get things ready for the "important fact," as $(-1)X+(1)Y\gt 0$.  Let $W=(-1)X+(1)Y$. Then $W$ has the shape described above, with $a=-1$ and $b=1$. Thus $W$ is normal with mean $(-1)(100)+(1)(120)=20$. The variance of $W$ is equal to $(-1)^2(25)+(1)^2(20)=45$. Now we want to find the probability that $W\gt 0$. This is the probability that the standard normal is greater than $\frac{0-20}{\sqrt{45}}$.

For the third problem, let $W$ be the random variable $2X+Y$. Then $W$ is normally distributed, mean $(2)(100)+(1)(120)$ and variance $(2)^2(25)+(1)^2(20)=120$. So we want to find the probability that a normal with mean $320$ and variance $120$ is $\lt 300$. That's a calculation you know how to do.

**Remark:** The problem did not specify independence, but undoubtedly expects you to assume it. Without *some* assumption about the joint distributions of $X$ and $Y$, we simply cannot solve (ii) or (iii).

Comment: I am still confused :( sorry.... like, for Y>X, why do we take Y-X? and then how did you get the mean 20 and variance 45? And doesn't the third question look very different than the second one?..any pointers on how to do it will be appreciated?

Comment: also, it mentions in the question: X and Y are normally distributed, independent random variables. with the mean and variance as given above. I am sorry if I missed any part of the question that might have caused confusion.

Comment: It did not cause confusion. I just thought that the person making up the problem might have carelessly not specified independence. It happens all too often! Since you still have questions, I will expand my answer.

Comment: Ok now I understand everything here. Thanks! :)

Comment: You are welcome. My first answer was quite brief, for completeness I should have done the third problem also.